# Create custom shape consisting of multiple single lines

Tags: wpf, shapes

i want to create a simple cross, that consists of two lines. The lines should have different colors. I've created a class that inherits form Shape. This class contains the two lines and computes the coordinates of the lines. I've read that i have to implement the DefiningGeometry property if i inherit from Shape. But how can i return both lines in the get section of that property?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a Path with an appropriate Geometry in its `Data` property? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data.aspx).

Comment: And when you say "the lines should have different colors", do you mean the two lines of the cross?

Comment: Yes. One line should be red and the other line blue

Comment: Then neither Shape nor Path is a good choice, because they only have a single `Stroke` brush. How about having a simple UserControl instead?

Comment: Then I will have a look on UserControls ... Thank you for that hint.

Comment: Alternatively you may also use GeometryDrawings. Pleas see my anser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could use the [`CombinedGeometry` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.aspx) to combine your lines together... the only thing is that you'll need to use [`LineGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.media.linegeometry.aspx) classes instead of `Line`s.  You could do something like this (from the linked `CombinedGeometry` page on MSDN):

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
  <Path.Data>

    <!-- Combines two geometries using the XOR combine mode. -->
    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Xor">
      <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="75,75" />
      </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
      <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="125,75" />
      </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
    </CombinedGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Of course, you'd want to replace these `EllipseGeometry` objects with `LineGeometry` objects, but that shouldn't be difficult as they have similar properties.

---

UPDATE >>>

Unfortunately, I don't think that you can use a `CombinedGeometry` object that contains geometries of different colours... the whole shape would have to be painted with one `Brush`. However, you *could* fake two colours with cleverly positioned `GradientStop`s. Also, as @Clemens mentioned, perhaps a `GeometryGroup` would be easier for you to use... try something like this:

```
<Path StrokeThickness="5" Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="50,0" EndPoint="50,100"  />
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,50" EndPoint="100,50"  />
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Stroke>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="0.475" />
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.475" />
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.525" />
            <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="0.525" />
            <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Path.Stroke>
</Path>
```

This `Brush` will appear as if it were actually different colours on the two lines:

[image]

Then all you'll need to do is to convert this into C# to return it from the `DefiningGeometry` property. Please use the examples from the linked pages and the [`GeometryGroup` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrygroup.aspx) page on MSDN to help you with this.

Comment: And `GeometryGroup` might be simpler (and easier to understand) than `CombinedGeometry`.

Comment: +1 You're right... it is easier. Good catch. Thanks, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may draw two differently colored lines by means of two GeometryDrawings in a DrawingBrush that fills a Rectangle:

```
<Rectangle Width="20" Height="20">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,-10 L0,10">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Brush="Blue" Thickness="3"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M-10,0 L10,0">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Brush="Red" Thickness="3"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```